# how to open URL in chrome with command line command and refresh page

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, dos

I want to open URL in using dos command, then i want to refresh same page by giving command to do **CTRL+R**  and  **CTRL+F5**.

I know how to open 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome www.yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write a vbscript and use "sendkeys" method. Check it out if it will help you.